# How to get sum of 2 numbers using JQuery

Tags: jquery

What I am trying to is, the user will enter the first number in the first textbox, then enter the second number in the second textbox. After the user presses the summation button, he will get the result in the result in the textbox under the summation button. Here is what I tried to do:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js">    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#add").click(function(){
        $("#sub") = parseFloat($("#a").value) + parseFloat($("#b").value);
      })
    })
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name="myform">
      <p>
        <input type="text" id="a">
        <input type="text" id="b">
      </p>

      <p>
        <input type="button" value = "+" id="add">
        <input type="text" id="sub">
      </p>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#sub") = parseFloat($("#a").val()) + parseFloat($("#b").val());
```

or

```
$("#sub") = parseFloat($("#a")[0].value) + parseFloat($("#b")[0].value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need use `.val` for value of input and for write sum into total input

```
  $("#add").click(function(){
    $("#sub").val((parseFloat($("#a").val()) + parseFloat($("#b").val())));
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7ak2e002/

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$("#sub") = parseFloat($("#a").value) + parseFloat($("#b").value);
```

to

```
$("#sub").val( parseFloat($("#a").val()) + parseFloat($("#b").val()) );
```

**Edit:**

$("#sub"), $("#a"), and $("#b") are jQuery objects.  Since they represent input objects, you need to use the jQuery val() method to get or set their values.  See here for more details: http://api.jquery.com/val/

On the other hand, if you want to use native Javascript "value" property, it would look like this:

```
document.getElementById( "sub" ).value = ( parseFloat( document.getElementById( "a" ).value ) + parseFloat( document.getElementById( "b" ).value ) );
```

Comment: You should explain the OP that you're suggesting to use jQuerys `val` method because jQuery wrapped sets do not feature native DOM properties like `value`.